# ¿Como obtener la longitud de una arreglo en C++?

Tags: c++, array, sizeof

Estoy intentando obtener la longitud de un arreglo en C++ desde una función que he creado con `sizeof()`, el código es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Calculo(int[]);

int main() {

    int alturasEdificios[] = {0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 1};

    int arrSize = sizeof(alturasEdificios) / sizeof(*alturasEdificios);

    printf("%d", arrSize);

    printf("\n%d", Calculo(alturasEdificios));

    return 0;
    system("pause");
}

int Calculo(int alturas[]) {

    int arrSize = sizeof(alturas) / sizeof(alturas[0]);
    return arrSize;
}
```

En método main, obtengo la longitud correcta del arreglo, pero desde la función el resultado de la longitud cambia y aunque puedo pasar como parámetro la longitud del arreglo desde la función main, me intriga saber porque obtengo resultados diferentes, de antemano gracias.

Comment: Si estas en  C++, porque no usas `std::array`, con el tienes la funcion `std::array::size` que te regresa el tamaño del array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> pero desde la función el resultado de la longitud cambia

Te recomiendo que actives los avisos del compilador, ya que al compilar con `-Wall -Wextra` nos da el aviso:

```
main.cpp:22:35: warning: 'sizeof (alturas)' will return the size of the pointer, not the array itself [-Wsizeof-pointer-div]
    int arrSize = sizeof(alturas) / sizeof(alturas[0]);
```

Ya que al final un `int[]` sin un tamaño definido es solo un `int*`. Entonces `Calculo` te retorna `sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int)`

Si quieres hacerlo usando funciones, tienes que darle uso a los templates:

```
// El tamaño del array se va calcular en tiempo de compilacion gracias a los templates
// La sintaxis es rara, int (&)[] es tomar un array por referencia.
template<size_t N>
int Calculo(int (&)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

Ahora, tu codigo es muy estilo C, asi que si quieres hacerlo estilo C, puedes usar un macro:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(X) sizeof(X)/sizeof(X[0])
```

Lo optimo es que utilices `std::array`. Ya que estas en C++, porque no aprovechar la librería estándar?

**Nota:** Por lo mismo de ver los avisos del compilador, tengo que avisarte que al final de tu codigo:

```
return 0;
system("pause");
```

Nunca se llega al `system("pause")`, ya que retornas de la funcion antes de llegar a el.

Comment: Gracias estuve investigando un poco a cerca del std::array, ya que es la primera vez que lo uso, ahora he encontrado otra forma de manejar los arreglos en C++, gracias!!!.

Comment: Un gusto, cualquier otra duda que tengas nos comentas